# Is there a way to view chrome.storage.local in Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Chrome Extension and I'm able to view background page localStorage on the Resources tab of Developer Tools.

Is there a way to do the same for chrome.storage.local?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb

Here are the docs for extending Devtools: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools

---

**Note**: the extension may be disabled by default in Chrome. Here's how to manually re-enable it (hat tip @reccanti):

https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2811969?hl=en

Comment: excellent extension - I vote that google buys it for millions and makes it part of devtools for extension developers!

Answer (score 0):

Use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) as mentioned in [Daniel Herr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633531/1011722). I wanted to add that it has been disabled by Chrome, though here's a way to manually re-enable it:

- https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2811969?hl=en