# Can't find local storage set in chrome extension using inspector

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Good day,

I'm working on a chrome extension and I am setting local storage variables within my background.js. Now I am trying to debug my extension and am trying to find the keys and values I set, but no matter what I inspect (whether the service worker or the application itself), local storage and session storage is always empty. View images below:

How I set data in background.js:

```js
const userData = JSON.stringify("authcode_123");
const nodeData = JSON.stringify("node_123");

chrome.storage.local.set(
    { userStatus: signIn, user_info: userData,
        node_info: nodeData, extStatus: true },
    function (response) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) resolve('fail');
        user_signed_in = signIn;
        resolve('success');
    }
);
```

When I test it using following code:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get(
    ['userStatus', 'user_info', 'node_info', 'extStatus'],
    function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

I get the correct values:

[image: Console log]

But everywhere the application memory is empty:

[image: Popup Inspect]

[image: Service Worker Inspect]

Anyone has any ideas what else I could inspect or do I have to reload the application storage somehow to see it?

Comment: same problem - did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the "local storage" accessible from the chrome.storage API is *not* the same as the Browser local storage from the "web storage API".
They make this distinction, albeit subtly, in the storage api page for extensions. (I certainly missed it!)

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/storage#usage

> Can extensions use web storage APIs? While extensions can use the
> Storage interface (accessible from window.localStorage) in some
> contexts (popup and other HTML pages), we don't recommend it for the
> following reasons: ...

There is, afaik, no built-in way to see the *extension* storage other than by console logging all over the place. But the extension described here works:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633531/20479

Yes, it's an extension to debug extensions. To see it, you need to open regular dev-tools (typically on your extension's service-worker) and look at the tab *on the far right*.

[image]